# join result from two database with different connection using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have two results from different queries and different connections, with the same parameter applicationid. I want to combine the results of the two queries.

this is the first query

```
const res = await db1Pool.query(
    `SELECT 
        a.user,
        a.applicationid,
        a.name,
        a.status
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.applicationid = b.applicationid
    WHERE a.status in ('CREATED', 'PAID')`
```

and this is the second query

```
const result = await db2Pool.query(
    `SELECT 
        a.applicationid,
        b.usia,
        b.homenumber,
        b.nohandphone,
        b.score,
        COUNT(*) OVER() AS all_row_count
    FROM table3 a
    LEFT JOIN table4 b ON b.applicationid = a.applicationid
    LEFT JOIN table5 c ON c.applicationid = a.applicationid
    WHERE a.applicationid is not null`
```

i have tried this way

```
const { rows: rowsDb1 } = res

let applicationId = rowsDb1.map(item => `'${item.applicationid }'`).join()
applicationId = applicationId ? `AND a.applicationid in (${applicationId})` : ''
```

and use the applicationId variable in the where state in the second query but only shows 10 rows from the first query.

In this case, the first query has a result of 10 rows and the second query has a result of 20 rows. I want to display the results of the second query, which is 20 rows with 10 rows of data from the first query. can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

So I guess the two queries work? but you have problems with merging the two arrays. I see many people now build nested loops, one over the second result and inside a loop the first to find the corresponding entry from the first results. however I like to use indexBy and groupBy methods of underscore for this. like this: (run `npm install underscore`)

```js
const res1ByApplicationId = _.indexBy(res1.rows, 'applicationId').
// and then go over the second to assign:
response2.rows.forEach(r => r.response1 = res1ByApplicationId[r.applicationId])
```

now it is easy with a single loop to go over this one list of res2 and create the ui.